# Making rspec work in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I've just installed RubyMine, as long as Ruby + gem + rspec + rspec-rails.

I'm trying to make run the mini-tutorial shown on http://rspec.info/ but I'm having problems.

First, I had to modify the shown

```
require 'bowling'
```

to

```
require_relative 'bowling'
```

as I was getting a

```
`require': no such file to load -- bowling.
```

Now, even after doing this I am getting a

```
`<top (required)>': undefined method `describe' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

How to make rspec work in RubyMine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a known issue:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-8603?projectKey=RUBY

EDIT: it did indeed seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

rspec.info is for RSpec version 1.x. Documentation for 2.x, which is what you will have installed if you simply did `gem install rspec` can be found at http://relishapp.com/rspec. You may want to take a look at their [tutorial](http://relishapp.com/rspec/file/twominutetutorial) there.

I use RSpec and RubyMine together every day, so I expect that version mismatch is your biggest problem.

Also, if you are willing to purchase a book to learn RSpec, I'd highly recommend http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book from Pragmatic Programmers.